# How to read from a specified file which is in a folder below without knowing the absolute path

Tags: node.js, file, csv, file-read

So I have my project directory:

[image]

Here I read ArticleFile:

```
 function _getDataFromFile() {
    var jsonArray = csvjson.toObject(fs.readFileSync('ArticleFile.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' }));

    var result = [];
    for (var idx = 0; idx < jsonArray.length; idx++) {
        var currArt = jsonArray[idx];
     //   if (!checkIfElementIsArticle(currArt))  throw "loaded object IS NOT an article!";

        result.push(new Article(currArt.imageLocation, currArt.title, currArt.description, parseInt(currArt.quantity),parseInt(currArt.price)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is if "ArticleFile.csv" is in lets say contentsKopie I have to know the absolute path such as :  `C:\Users\noone_000\Desktop\BSD\Hausübungen\WebServer\WebServer\contentsKopie\ArticleFile.csv` . How can I set the path like: `fs.readFileSync('/ContentsCopie/ArticleFile.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' })`

PS: csvjson is a module (require("csvjson"))

Answer (score 0):

When you start the path with `/` it is interpreted as an absolute path. If you want to open a file in sub directory, you can use `./ContentsCopie/ArticleFile.csv`

The `.` in front of the slash means that the path is relative to the current directory.

Conversely, if you needed to go up a level you can prefix your path with `..`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `./contentsKopie/ArticleFile.csv` enough?

When using `/contentsKopie/ArticleFile.csv` it's actually looking in `C:/contentsKopie/ArticleFile.csv`. So you have to prepend your path with a `.` to tell it to start at the working directory (WebServer here).

Otherwise, you can have the absolute path of the current file with `__dirname` then you could compose your path using the `path` module from node.

```
var path = require('path');
var article = path.join(__dirname, './contentsKopie/ArticleFile.csv');
```

This way, you'll get the absolute path of your file.